# Custom Security in ASP.NET MVC For Applications (Not mass market web sites)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I'm building a SaaS app and have some issues in dealing with authorization and ASP.NET MVC. I have a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392074/help-with-2-part-question-on-asp-net-mvc-and-custom-security-design) and this is kind of taking a cue from comments there. I need to provide somewhat granular security (e.g. lots of permissions) for each user. I realize that any discretionary system can be modeled as a roles system by just creating more roles. But that's a lot more roles than I want to deal with. I don't think roles is going to work for me and would like to work more at the permissions level.

I know the standard response to any question dealing with ASP.NET and authorization is create all your application users as Windows users and implement the ASP.NET Membership Provider. One issue, I'm not going to create Windows users. My question is can the standard ASP.NET MVC AuthorizeAttribute and AuthorizeCore be made to fit with a permissions model?

Also, apparently, the impetus here is really that ASP.NET MVC Caching will break a custom security implementation. Obviously, I don't want my pages to run slowly but I'm not sure I want this caching at all. I'm building a business application; is caching everything really appropriate? It seems that caching would just make concurrency problems much more difficult than they already are. For example, if I am caching all of my customer info pages, including the edit pages, then won't I be defeating any concurrency controls I would have in place (say, timestamp checking)?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I wouldn't create the users as Windows users, but rather store them in a SQL database.  So you now have complete control over how you want to associate your security needs with your users.

Once you do that you can then create a custom security filter by creating a class that implements IAuthorizationFilter.  That way you have the control you want to do whatever validation you want, roles based, permissions based, day of the week based, whatever.

You then just attribute your service methods with your new custom security filter, and pass along whatever info you need to ensure that the calling user has the appropriate rights/roles to execute the method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do certainly not need to make application users windows users. the default out of the box MVC has them as users stored in a sql database.

Edit Pages typically should not be cached as they will not really be loaded multiple times with the same data within the cache lifespan.  my thought process is that MVC is easy enough to add caching that I would build it out first then performance test to see if it is even a necessary step.  (Remember that unless you are looking at large large numbers of client connections then it is typically more economical to make a slightly less performant code and beef up the server hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create Windows users to use the ASP.NET Membership provider, it uses SQL tables to store the membership objects. Yes, you can use the Authorize attribute with the membership provider, for example, in a page that only "admins" can edit, you'll use the authorize attribute as follow:

[Authorize(Users = "Admin")]

Also, you don't want to be caching pages where users are going to be editing data, use caching (and you can do it a lot) in areas designated for anonymous users - users with no edit rights.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer my question. This is still about Roles. My comment about Windows users was just out of frustration at a lot of answers on SO. I'm trying not to use Roles.